# Sorted list in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was wondering if it is possible/good to maintain a sorted list in database.

For example, I have a list of items with priority 1~100. Every time I insert, the database can insert it into proper position, so that when I call `.select(20)`, the database can return me the first 20 items with the highest priority.

Answer (score 6):

Add A field called priority. Fill it with data appropriately and sort by it and depending on your database select the top 20 e.g.

```
SELECT TOP 20 [Your fields here] 
FROM   table 
ORDER  BY priority
```

or

```
SELECT [Your fields here] 
FROM   table 
ORDER  BY priority 
LIMIT 20
```

Adding an index for the field would probably be a good idea as well.

This is a very durable solution. Any other solution that takes advantage of the order the rows are physically stored in the table would be very fragile.

Comment: I hesitate to all this a durable solution, until databases support the ANSI `FETCH FIRST # ROWS ONLY`.

Comment: @OMG Ponies. Ok fair enough. Would you say its as durable as the  vendor for the vendor specific implmentation?

Comment: This is the correct solution. Just include the priority as the last col in your PK or clustered index, or create a unique non-clustered index ok (PK, priority) and you will be fine. Then order is guaranteed and not implementation specific.

Comment: One that I tend to do that most people find odd is to make the priority column a float. That way, you can *generally* insert a new row between any two existing rows by averaging their priorities. Only very rarely do you have to renumber the priorities of multiple rows.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if it is possible/good
>   to maintain a sorted list in database.

See @Conrad Frix's answer to discover that it is indeed possible (using the windowed function `ROW_NUMBER()` is another approach that has the advantage of being Standard SQL and supported in SQL Server). Note that this adds a column to a table (an attribute to a relvar, if you will), which isn't a 'sorted list' but seems to be what you require.

Is a good idea? Clearly, if this is a requirement on you application/enterprise then it is indeed appropriate to maintain the values in the database.

> Every time I insert, the database can
>   insert it into proper position

Note that if you have 100 rows with unique `priority` attribute values 1-100 and you need to `INSERT` a value at, say, `priority = 55`, the existing values 55-100 would need to be incremented by one and the database will not do that for you unless you have written procedural code in a database object to do so (e.g. a trigger). If you only have to manage `INSERT`s (and not `UPDATE`s nor `DELETE`s) then prehaps a better approach would be to start off with larger gaps e.g. your initial 100 rows could have `priority` values 1000, 2000, 3000,...100000. Now the same `INSERT` as before can go between 54000 and 55000 by assigning it the attribute `priority = 54500` without the need to reassign any values.